# Motivating the multiplication of real numbers

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic, real-numbers, math-history, motivation

What are some of the ways in which one can motivate the multiplication of real numbers?

The sum of two real numbers can be thought in terms of **jumps along a horizontal line**. For example, (3)+(-2) may be "interpreted" as follows: initially "a thing" is sitting down over number 3 and then it jumps two unities to the left; it falls over number 1.

Do you know of a similar way to "think of" the multiplication of reals numbers?

Even though the multiplication can be thought as a short way to express certain sums (for example, 5*3 is just another way of saying 5+5+5), I am looking forward to reading 'bout geometric ways to motivate or introduce the operation.

Do you know if a connection with smilar triangles can or has been established once?

Please, forgive me in advance for the vagueness and/or naïveté of this question of mine.

Comment: Area of a rectangle?

Comment: similar figures? if you want to multiply $ab$, you start with placing on $x$ axis a segment long $a$ and on $y$ axis a segment long 1 and a segment long $b$; the rectangle similar to the one with sides $a$ and 1 has sides $ab$ and $b$.